# UWP app crash immediately after opening with Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll Event Log

Tags: c#, windows, dll, uwp, event-viewer

I have developed a UWP app and uploaded it to Windows Store. Everything was working perfectly fine until I created a new self-signing certificate after the previous one expired and re-published the new changes to the store. The application after downloading and installing from the store crashes immediately after opening and leaves an event log with the below error in the Windows Event Viewer. The same issue occurs when installing through a side-loading build.

I have tried all methods suggested online(running system scan for corrupted files, register dll, use dll file from another system, etc). I have also uploaded an [image](https://prnt.sc/26gpxmz) showing my windows version. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Faulting application name: XYZWindowsApps.exe, version: 1.0.1.0, time stamp: 0x61e99c28

Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1466, time stamp: 0xe01c7650

Exception code: 0xc000027b

Fault offset: 0x000000000010b362

Faulting process id: 0x2d0c

Faulting application start time: 0x01d80e24b18250ad

Faulting application path: C:\Program
Files\WindowsApps\NameXYZ.AppName_1.0.13.0_x64__tesn1012p7f1y\XYZWindowsApps.exe

Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll

Report Id: 07e3f487-1127-4f89-ba1b-1e1cb032168c

Faulting package full name: NameXYZ.AppName_1.0.13.0_x64__tesn1012p7f1y

Faulting package-relative application ID: App

Comment: Base on your description, it 's more related with self-signing certificate, have you tried test certificate in local with VS manually?